# Showing rows 0 - 9 ( 10 total, Query took 0.0002 sec) [LatestMoodTime: [BLOB - 10B] - [BLOB - 0B]]

Tags: mysql, sql

What does it mean showing 0-9 when there are 10 results? this is causing issues with mysql_num_rows

This is the MYSQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `members` 
WHERE (
LOWER(  `RealName` ) LIKE  '%hot%'
OR LOWER(  `UserName` ) LIKE  '%hot%'
OR LOWER(  `Location` ) LIKE  '%hot%'
OR LOWER(  `LatestMood` ) LIKE  '%hot%'
)
ORDER BY  `LatestMoodTime` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by `showing 0-9 when there are 10 results`?

Comment: I've copied and pasted that from phpmyadmin .. i dont know what it means by only showing 9 out of 10 either

Answer (score 2):

The result array is zero-based, so "0-9" means there are 10 elements, index starting from 0 and ending at 9.